# How to register lucene in dependency injection?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, lucene.net

I am having trouble to find information about registering the different building blocks of Lucene into the dependency injection.
I am also not sure about the lifetimes.

I think one should reuse the IndexWriter as it seems to be costly. And i managed to do so.

But when it comes to search im lost.
Should i have DI handle the IndexReader or the LuceneDictionary as well as the AnalyzingInfixSuggester ? And how could this be done.

This is how i went for now:

Registration:

```
 public static IServiceCollection AddLucene(this IServiceCollection services)
 {
     var version = Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48;
     var directory = new RAMDirectory();
     var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(version);
     var config = new IndexWriterConfig(version, analyzer);
     var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config);

     services.AddSingleton(writer);
     services.AddSingleton(analyzer);
     services.AddSingleton(directory);

     services.AddTransient<SearchService>();
     services.AddTransient<IndexService>();
        
     return services;
 }
```

IndexWriter:

```
    public IndexService(IndexWriter writer)
    { 
        _writer = writer;
    }

    public void WriteIndex()
    {        
        var searchResults = QueryDatabase();
        
        var idField = new StringField(nameof(SearchResult.DatabaseId), "", Field.Store.YES);
        var headField = new StringField(nameof(SearchResult.Header), "", Field.Store.YES);
        var bodyField = new TextField(nameof(SearchResult.Body), "", Field.Store.YES);
        var typeField = new TextField(nameof(SearchResult.Type), "", Field.Store.YES);

        var doc = new Document
        {
            idField,
            headField,
            bodyField,
            typeField
        };

        foreach (var result in searchResults)
        {
            idField.SetStringValue(result.DatabaseId);
            headField.SetStringValue(result.Header);
            bodyField.SetStringValue(result.Body);
            typeField.SetStringValue(result.Type);
            _writer.AddDocument(doc);
        }
        _writer.Commit();
    }
```

Search:

```
    public SearchService(StandardAnalyzer analyzer, RAMDirectory directory)
    { 
        _analyzer = analyzer;
        _directory = directory;
    }

    public SearchResponse Search(string input, int page)
    { 
        var reader = DirectoryReader.Open(_directory);
        var searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        var multiFieldQP = new MultiFieldQueryParser(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, _searchFields, _analyzer);
        var _input = EscapeSearchTerm(input.Trim());
        var query = multiFieldQP.Parse(_input);

        var docs = searcher.Search(query, null, 1000).ScoreDocs;
        ...
    }

    public List<string> SearchAhead(string input)
    {
        var reader = DirectoryReader.Open(_directory);
        var dictionary = new LuceneDictionary(reader, nameof(SearchResult.Header));

        using var analyzingSuggester = 
            new AnalyzingInfixSuggester(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, new RAMDirectory(), _analyzer);

        analyzingSuggester.Build(dictionary);
        var lookupResultList = analyzingSuggester.DoLookup(input.Trim(), false, 9);
        ...
    }
```

Most of this code is based on https://beckshome.com/2022/11/lucene-blazor-part-3-auto-complete and i modified it to work with asp.net core api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an interesting question but for me I only use dependency injection if I have multiple types of the dependency that I might chose to use and it's important to be able to swap out those types system wide easily.

So that is to say I didn’t personally put any aspects of Lucene in my DI container.

You could of course registering the `IndexWriter` as a singleton if you are using NRT (Near REAL TIME) readers.

But that only makes sense if you are using Lucene.NET to manage a single index.  Otherwise you'd probably need to wrap that `IndexWriter` in a custom type that helps you know which index it's a writer for.  Then that custom type could be registered in DI as a singleton and provide static access to the associated `IndexWriter`.

Comment: I finally understand. Usally one index does not meet the requirements. I found this out after playing around more with lucene.net. Same goes for search. Anyways thanks for the answer

Comment: Yah, and people sometimes think to put multiple "record" types in one Lucene index and that can certainly work, in fact Lucene invites this due to it's document model since documents don't need to have the same fields. But with Lucene it's almost always more efficient to have all the documents (ie records) have the same set of fields and if you need to index different types of documents do it via another Lucene Index.  The reason is due to how Lucene stores it's index offsets in memory.  This matters most if you are indexing lots of docs. Say 1,000,000+